# How to display properly a web page on all mobile browsers

Tags: android, html, mobile, browser

I've shared this screenshot to show you how it's displayed on all android browsers:

[image: Browser Comparison]

I used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3">` but it seems to work only on android default browser.

I have put together a [link for testing](http://www.pausapizza.it/test/step1_indirizzo-incompleto.html)

The correct view should be like the Android default browser, with an adjustment of the 100% in width, in either vertical or horizontal mode.

Comment: maybe firefox and chrome's user configs are causing a problem. I know that Opera for android has an option called 'Single Column View' which sometimes changes the layout of the page drastically. Maybe chrome and firefox have similar options. Try resetting the configs of both to default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can fix this is to set the view-port to the width of your document. Each browser and device has a different pixel width for displayable area or default. Change the view port to the following:

```
<!-- When viewing your css and live widths I got 944 wrapper width,
update if incorrect -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=944" />
```

The only other way to get it to show the same is to use a mobile doctype instead of html5. But this can break some functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
```